# How to toggle the "src" attribute of an image without using an if-statement?

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, onclick, toggle

the problem is I want to change the src of img tag by using the button which executes if, else function. but I think my code is unprofessional and there is a better way to do the same job.

```js
let smile = true  
let test = () => {
   if (smile == true) {
     document.getElementById("image").src = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/adb/fruit-in-a-bowl-1637721.jpg";
      smile = false
    } 
 else {
     document.getElementById("image").src = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/a33/fresh-red-ripe-strawberries-1641723.jpg";
     smile = true
    }
}
```

```html
 <img id="image" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/a33/fresh-red-ripe-strawberries-1641723.jpg" width="160" height="120">
 <button type="button" onclick="test()">over here </button>
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Your code makes it so clicking once will set up the image to change on the next click.

Comment: i just want to know if is there any other solution for doing that

Comment: There are many other ways, but nothing wrong with your way (except that you should get the reference to the image just once and before the function even executes so that you don't have to keep searching the DOM for the same element over and over again).

Comment: can you tell me the best optimization true and falls statement is like a cube of sugar whenever I can't solve a problem I use it . want some creativity

Comment: @ErfanTa Wdym u want creativity. You have a code that works and is fine, so use it?! Why change it

Comment: @HackerFrosch gets shorter and  for clarity, i just feel my solution is not professional

Comment: @ErfanTa ... The OP might check on a late provided entirely generic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution, wich is just 5 lines of JS. It uses if-else oneliners, to wich a detailed guide can be found [here](https://www.codingem.com/javascript-if-else-on-one-line/).

I also used the HTML data-attribute instead of a variable:
`data-smile="false"`

I removed the id of the Element because you can just select it via the data-attribute.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('[data-smile]');
img.onclick = () => {
    img.dataset.smile = img.dataset.smile == "true" ? "false" : "true";
    img.src = img.dataset.smile == "true" ? "https://i.imgur.com/jgyJ7Oj.png" : "https://i.imgur.com/PqpOLwp.png";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PqpOLwp.png" data-smile="false">
</div>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Great job with ternary if

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your question that you want the same goal but in an other code-way: you can use `img.onclick = () => { ... }`

here is example for that

```js
let img = document.getElementById('img');
let isSmile
img.onclick = () => { 
  if(isSmile) {
    img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/PqpOLwp.png";
    isSmile = false
    }
  else {
    img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/jgyJ7Oj.png";
    isSmile = true
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PqpOLwp.png" id="img">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little improvement: `img.onclick = () => {` Just a little shorter

Answer (score 0):

I propose a generic approach where one would toggle the image source between a primary (maybe the OP's *"smile"* state) and a secondary (*"no smile"*) source.

An implementation then makes use of [`data-*` global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) like e.g. `data-primary-toggle-src`, `data-secondary-toggle-src` and maybe a `data-toggle-state` as well as of such an image element's related [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property for reading the to be alternated image sources and writing the current toggle state (e.g. `'primary'` versus `'secondary'`).

The generic approach and the encapsulated implementation makes this code re-usable (e.g. multiple time re-use within the same document or in other projects).

```js
function initializeToggleImages() {
  function toggleImageStates({ currentTarget: imgNode }) {
    const { dataset, src: currentSrc } = imgNode;

    // read.
    const primarySrc = dataset.primaryToggleSrc;
    const secondarySrc = dataset.secondaryToggleSrc;

    const isPrimaryState = (primarySrc === currentSrc);

    // write / toggle.
    imgNode.src = isPrimaryState && secondarySrc || primarySrc;
    dataset.toggleState = isPrimaryState && 'secondary' || 'primary';

    console.log({ toggleState: dataset.toggleState });
  }
  document
    .querySelectorAll('img[data-secondary-toggle-src]')
    .forEach(imgNode =>
      imgNode.addEventListener('click', toggleImageStates)
    )
}
initializeToggleImages();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
img[data-secondary-toggle-src] { width: 160px; height: 120px; cursor: pointer; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; left: auto!important; width: 50%; }
```

```html
<img
  src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/312/3888/2592.jpg?hmac=Lk5n0q19XuicLgvYPdAr5iML0VbkEADyqgJoHH_5nAs"
  data-primary-toggle-src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/312/3888/2592.jpg?hmac=Lk5n0q19XuicLgvYPdAr5iML0VbkEADyqgJoHH_5nAs"
  data-secondary-toggle-src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/248/3872/2592.jpg?hmac=_F3LsKQyGyWnwQJogUtsd_wyx2YDYnYZ6VZmSMBCxNI"
  title="toggle me"
/>

<img
  src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/515/4585/3439.jpg?hmac=WSSTufs9yyQUM8j16-DUr6nfucMBKIw7XHyMruISqeQ"
  data-primary-toggle-src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/512/3434/4340.jpg?hmac=DMhjASC-MZzL9bg0VcfO7vXLZscfbcjNLm7Rosmo0iw"
  data-secondary-toggle-src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/515/4585/3439.jpg?hmac=WSSTufs9yyQUM8j16-DUr6nfucMBKIw7XHyMruISqeQ"
  title="toggle me"
/>
```